# How do I use regex to replace non-word chars in a specific piece of string?

Tags: vb.net, regex, replace

I have text file with a row like this:

```
SendersTimeSeriesIdentification: COMPANY_A/COMPANY_B/REF_7/20090505
```

I'd like to replace all non-word chars in the value part with the character `n`, like this:

```
SendersTimeSeriesIdentification: COMPANYnAnCOMPANYnBnREFn7n20090505
```

But there are similar strings all over the file, which must remain intact. An example being:

```
MessageIdentification: REF_7/VER_1/20090505
```

I think I must use lookbehind, and I came to this attempt (VB.NET):

```
Regex.Replace(fileContentString, "(?<=SendersTimeSeriesIdentification: )(\W)", "0")
```

This doesn't work as I'd like it to. So my questions are:
Is it possible to replace all non-word characters in a specific piece of string with just one Regex.Replace call? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Regex.Replace(fileContentString, "(?<=SendersTimeSeriesIdentification:\s.*)[_\W]", "0")
```

This replaces all \W and _ chars with "0" after "SendersTimeSeriesIdentification: ".

Comment: I'll use this solution, just because it is easier in my situation.

I guess this would not work if the line would have a comment at the end (// some comment), becuse the two forward slashes would get replaced, even though they shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing as a single regex replace, I'd split the file into lines, then only process lines that start with "SendersTimeSeriesIdentification: ". 
That way the regex replacement is nice and simple.

Comment: Kamarey's answer is correct, but I would take this approach if I could.

Comment: @Alan M: I agree. The "if I could" is the key here. :-)